# how to list all the nodes of a package?

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting used to ROS and I've found several times commands have the following syntax:

command package_name package_node

then it raises a question "How can I list all the nodes of that package??" to use in such commands??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45710/how-to-list-all-the-nodes-of-a-package?/) by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2012-10-12

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2012-10-12**:
Maybe I'm misinterpreting your question, but if you're talking about running commands in your shell, (like rosrun, roslaunch) tab auto-completion works with ROS commands too.  Tabbing twice should give you all the options you can use.

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-10-12**:
rosrun robotino_navigation executables [args] -> I think that's only possible to search for all possible packages. In this case, when I tab again to find all the possible executables but it ROS cursor doesn't show these hints

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-10-12**:
@joq & @tbh: that solves half of my problem. Thank you!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-10-13**:
Since you still have a problem, please edit your question to add additional information about it, or open a new question, whichever makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @tbh said, shell auto-completion will list all the nodes by pressing the *tab* key twice like this:

```
$ rosrun package_name <tab><tab>
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2017-02-05**:
This doesn't work on all platforms. i.e. Raspian doesn't support tab-completion.

**Comment by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on 2017-06-20**:
Tab completion works, but there should be a command for that.

**Comment by [fabian](https://answers.ros.org/users/56325/fabian/) on 2020-11-05**:
Also: Doesn't this list the *executable name*, not the *node name*?